# Using train_test_split over a list of dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, train-test-split

I have a 12 feature data frames named as `X[0]`, `X[1]`... till `X[11]` and corresponding to it 12 response data frames as `y[0]` to `y[11]`. I need to split them into train and test data frames using the train_test_split function. As this processes empty lists `(X_train[], X_test[], y_train[] and y_test[])` simple assignment:

```
b = 0    
while b < 12:
    X_train[b], X_test[b], y_train[b], y_test[b] = train_test_split(X[b], y[b], random_state=0)
    b = b + 1
```

gives this error:

> IndexError: list assignment index out of range

I don't know how to use `append()` function here.
Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Do all your feature data frames have the same features or does each feature data frame represent a different set of features?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a for loop. Just write

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, 
                            test_size=0.2, random_state=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
X_train = []
X_test = []
y_train = []
y_test = []



for i in range(0,12):
    a, b, c, d = train_test_split(X[i], y[i], test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

    X_train.append(a)
    X_test.append(b)
    y_train.append(c)
    y_test.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it as follows:

```
while b < 12:
    X_t, X_te, y_t, y_te = train_test_split(X[b], y[b], random_state=0)
    X_train.append(X_t)
    X_test.append(X_te)
    y_train.append(y_t)
    y_test.append(y_te)

    b = b + 1
```